# Restoring a backup from Sol 8.2.0 results in empty index

Tags: solr

We are running Solr 8.2.0 as a standalone system with multiple cores. To test backups, I used the following command:

```
sudo -u solr curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/debt/replication?command=backup&lo
cation=/tmp/solrbackups/debt/'
```

The response I got from the following command:

```
sudo -u solr curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/debt/replication?command=details&wt=xml'
```

was:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>

<lst name="responseHeader">
  <int name="status">0</int>
  <int name="QTime">3</int>
</lst>
<str name="status">OK</str>
<lst name="details">
  <str name="indexSize">119 bytes</str>
  <str name="indexPath">/var/solr/data/debt/data/restore.20191211201823908</str>
  <arr name="commits">
    <lst>
      <long name="indexVersion">1576093177904</long>
      <long name="generation">1233</long>
      <arr name="filelist">
        <str>segments_y9</str>
      </arr>
    </lst>
  </arr>
  <str name="isMaster">true</str>
  <str name="isSlave">false</str>
  <long name="indexVersion">1576093177904</long>
  <long name="generation">1233</long>
  <lst name="master">
    <arr name="replicateAfter">
      <str>commit</str>
    </arr>
    <str name="replicationEnabled">true</str>
  </lst>
</lst>
</response>
```

Then I ran a delete command to test out restoring the index from the backup by using:

```
sudo -u solr curl http://localhost:8983/solr/debt/update -H "Content-type: text/xml" --data-binary '<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>'
```

Then I stopped and started Solr via /etc/init.d/solr stop|start

When I ran the following command:

```
sudo -u solr curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/debt/replication?command=restore&location=/tmp/solrbackups/debt/'
```

I got a Status OK from the command line.

But when I go to the web API to look at the core, it shows that there are no documents.

Has anyone else had this problem?

Comment: So what is the contents of `/tmp/solrbackups/debt/`? According to your details page there is no information about a backup taking place (there should be a `<backup>` element with the status there according to the docs. Does the server side Solr log say anything useful? The details page is just the normal replication handler detail page.

Comment: The log shows no active events.

The contents of the direction /tmp/solrbackups/debt:

`code`
drwxr-xr-x  3 solr solr 4096 Dec 11 19:47 .
drwxr-xr-x 12 solr solr 4096 Dec 11 19:47 ..
drwxrwxr-x  2 solr solr 4096 Dec 11 19:47 snapshot.20191211194706618

Comment: I have the same problem do you have an update on this?